# Turn String aaaabbbbddd into a4b4d3

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to get a head start on practicing interview questions and I came across this one:

Turn String aaaabbbbddd into a4b4d3

You would basically want to convert the existing string into a string with each unique character occurrence and the number of times the character occurs.

This is my solution but I think it could be refined into something more elegant:

```
    String s = "aaaabbbbddd";
    String modified = "";
    int len = s.length();
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        count = 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
            if (c[i] == ' ') {
                break;
            }
            if (c[i] == c[j]) {
                count++;
                c[j] = ' ';
            }

        }
        if (c[i] != ' ') {
            modified += c[i] + "" +  count; 

        }
    }
    System.out.println(modified);
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions for a solution?

Comment: This type of question belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: are the strings always coming in that way? nothing like aaabbbdddaa? In that case, will you expect a5b3d3 or a3b3d3a2?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is really request for a code review.

Comment: What would make this on-topic? Having a bug in it? Having only a partial code snippet?  This still seems like a coding question, think of it like a puzzle.  I can write that code in X-1 lines... Oh yeah? I can write that code in X-5 lines, and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Employ a `Map<Character, Integer>` instead.  Attempt to insert the new character into the map; if it already exists, then increment the value for that particular character.

Example:

```
Map<Character, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();
if(!countMap.containsKey('a')) {
    countMap.put('a', 1);
} else {
    countMap.put('a', countMap.get('a') + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To add on to @Makoto's wonderful answer, in your situation, I would use a `TreeMap` instead of a `HashMap`. A `TreeMap` will allow you to print in alphabetical order.  I have also added the print code to show you how it would look. It's fully runnable.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class MapPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

        String blah = "aaaabbbbddd";

        for (int i = 0; i < blah.length(); i++) {
            char c = blah.charAt(i);
            if (!map.containsKey(c)) {
                map.put(c, 1);
            } else {
                map.put(c, (map.get(c) + 1));
            }
        } 

        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry: map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.print(entry.getKey() + "" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Output with `TreeMap`: **`a4b4d3`**

Output with `HashMap`: **`d3b4a4`**

Answer (score 1):

My version

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 0;
    char last = s.charAt(0);
    for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == last) {
            count++;
        } else {
            sb.append(last).append(count);
            count = 0;
            last = c;
        }
    }
    if (count != 0) {
        sb.append(last).append(count);
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I tried.

I think you can't ask for a simpler code than this.

```
    String s = "aaaabbbbddd", modified = "";
    int len = s.length(),  i = 0,  j = i + 1,  count = 1;
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();
    for (; i < len; i = j) {
        count = 1;
            for (; j < len; j++) 
                 if (c[i] == c[j]) 
                 count++;
                    else {
                    j++;
                    break;
                    }
        modified += c[i] + "" + count;
    }
    System.out.println(modified);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you find this useful.

Method 1

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the string : ");
    String str = scan.nextLine();
    char c;

    char[] charArr = str.toCharArray();

    LinkedHashMap<Character,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < charArr.length ; i++)
    {
        c = charArr[i];
        if(map.containsKey(c) || map.containsKey(c-32))
        {
            if(c<97)
            {
                map.put(c,map.get(c)+1);
            }
            else
            {
                map.put(c,map.get(c)+1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            map.put((char)(c+32),1);
        }
    }

    for(Map.Entry e : map.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.print(""+e.getKey()+""+e.getValue());
    }
```

Method 2

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the string : ");
    String str = scan.nextLine();              
    String newStr = "";
    char c;
    int count = 1;

    char[] charArr = str.toCharArray();          


    for(int i = 0 ; i < charArr.length ; i++)        
    {
        c = charArr[i];                          

        if(i>0)
        {
            if ( c == charArr[i-1] || c == (char)(charArr[i-1]+32) )
            {
                count++;                      
            }
            else
            {
                if(c < 97)
                {
                    newStr = newStr + count;
                    count = 1;
                    newStr = newStr + (char)(c+32);
                }
                else
                {
                    newStr = newStr + count;
                    count = 1;
                    newStr = newStr + c;                 
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(c < 97)
            {
                newStr = newStr + (char)(c+32);
            }
            else
            {
                newStr = newStr + (char)c;              
            }
        }


    }
    newStr = newStr + count;
    System.out.print(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner S=new Scanner(System.in);
        String in=S.next();
        int count=1;
        String out="";
        for(int i=0;i<in.length()-1;){
            out+=in.charAt(i+1);
            count=1;
            if(in.charAt(i)!=in.charAt(i+1)){
                out+=count;
                i++;
            }else{
                while(i<in.length()-1){
                    if(in.charAt(i)==in.charAt(i+1)){
                        count++;
                        i++;
                    }
                    else{
                        i++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                out+=count;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(out);
        
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution

```
public String countChars(String in){
 LinkedHashMapMap<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
 for(char c: in.toCharArray()){
   Integer count =  map.get(c);
   if(count==null){
    count=0;
   }
   count++;
   map.put(c,count);
 }
 String out ="";
 for(Entry<Character, Integer> e : map.entrySet()){
    out += e.getKey()+e.getValue();
 }
 return out;
}
```